# indentation in ts (translation source) file is not working in Qt

Tags: qt, internationalization, translation, language-translation

Spaces are not working for indentation in ts file.
Is there any tag which can be used for indentation like like br is used for line break

I want to display text as follows:

```
     1. Please press telecom handler
        button.
```

while it is shown as

```
 1. Please press telecom handler
 button.
```

How to indent first and second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help!! 
I have used 
    <blockquote >
html tag for indentation

Answer (score 0):

If your text widget is successfully parsing `<br/>` tag from translator, you may want to use `&nbsp;` or `&#160;` for non-breakable space.

Comment: @user746184 Please edit your question, and format desired text as code, to preserve indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!
I have used 
     <blockquote> </blockquote>
html tag for indentation.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a `QLabel`, you could use rich text in the label, and then use HTML ordered list tags, as in:

```
<ol>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) for more information on HTML lists.